# Progress Bar with Custom List

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

Hey I am trying to implement a custom movies list using the holder pattern. Currently, I am successfully displaying the list. I want to display a progress bar with some message before the only activity get's loaded. I can't seem to wrap my head around the progress bar with async task and I have followed some examples but can't seem to understand them , can someone please advise where and what to insert in order for it to work. I would really appreciate that.

Here is my only activity

```
 public class MovieRatingsActivity extends ListActivity
    {
    private ArrayList<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initializeUI();
    }

    private void initializeUI()
    {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
           this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);      
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(   R.raw.ratings);
        movies = Movie.loadFromFile(inputStream);       
        setListAdapter(new RowIconAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, R.id.row_label, movies));
    }

    //declare a static holder class
    public static class ViewHolder{
        ImageView icon;
        TextView movieText,votesText;
    }

    /** Custom row adatper -- that displays an icon next to the movie name */
    class RowIconAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> 
    {
        private ArrayList<Movie> movies;        
        public RowIconAdapter(Context c, int rowResourceId, int textViewResourceId, 
                ArrayList<Movie> items)
        {
            super(c, rowResourceId, textViewResourceId, items);
            movies  = items;
        }

        public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            //declare a holder object
            ViewHolder holder;
            Movie currMovie = movies.get(pos);

            //nly inflate view once and get all the views once
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_icon);
                holder.movieText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_label);
                holder.votesText= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_subtext);

                //set the holder class
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }

            else{
                //get all the views once done
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            //set all the values in the list
            holder.movieText.setText(currMovie.getName());
            String votesStr = currMovie.getVotes()+" votes";
            holder.votesText.setText(votesStr);
            Bitmap movieIcon = getMovieIcon(currMovie.getName(), currMovie.getRating());
            holder.icon.setImageBitmap(movieIcon);

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

My layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can insert progress bar when you are running service to get data and on completion dismiss the progress bar.

Comment: Can you please show an example code with async task as that something i am finding hard to understand? Cheers

Comment: I add the answer through which you will get the idea how to go with the progressbar functionality in your code,

Answer (score 1):

Make an asynctask in wich you initiate the loading bar, and when asynctask is finished, just dismiss it.

public class MyAsync extends AsyncTask>{

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Show you progress bar
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
          InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(   
                R.raw.ratings);
          movies = Movie.loadFromFile(inputStream);            
          return movies;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        //Hide your progress bar.
        setListAdapter(new RowIconAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, R.id.row_label, movies));

    }
}
```

And then call this AsyncTask in your OnCreate or wherever you want to show your Movie list.

Comment: Quick question what type of parameters does this async task take and what is the purpose?

Comment: <TypeOfVarArgParams, ProgressValue, ResultValue>

Comment: take a look at this tuto: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#asynctask

Comment: Hey I tried this code but it breaks the list :( @Fakher

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9JFJYA09Kn6Ums3V29WZjYtd2M

Comment: what do you mean by breaks the list ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46910898/asynctask-breaks-custom-listview/46911526#46911526 @fakher

Comment: The list was loading fine before the async thingy.

Comment: Okay now its working but I can't see the progress bar before activity load at all.

Comment: you must instantiate it, make it visible in onPreExecute and than dismiss it in onPostExecute

Answer (score 1):

In **onPreExecute** initialize your progress bar and do some like this:

```
 @Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    try {
        createProgressBar(context);   // add methodology of your progressbar here,     
       }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception: >> "+e.toString());
    }
```

and after getting results in **onPostExecute** dismiss the progressbar

```
   @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
    super.onPostExecute(o);

    try {
        cancelProgressBar();   // here add your progressbar to be dismissed.
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception: >> "+e.toString());
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "On_Post");
}
```

I hope it gives you the idea how it can be done.